# Pyspark: oracle.xdb.XMLType class not found when reading XML from Oracle

Tags: java, xml, oracle, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to read data from Oracle database from Spark 2.3.0.
Some of the columns of the tables are in xml format.
My program fails on java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.xdb.XMLType when some action is called.

For reading I am using:

```
spark.read.format("jdbc") \
            .option("url", dbc_url) \
            .option("user", user_name) \
            .option("password", password) \
            .option("dbtable", query) \
            .option("driver", "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver") \
            .option("fetchsize", 10_000) \
            .load()
```

I tried to download different versions of ojdbc.jar, xdb.jar and xmlparserv2.jar but nothing made a difference so far. I submit the job in cluster mode and other jars seem to work fine.

```
OJDBC=deployment/libs/ojdbc8.jar
MSSQL=deployment/libs/mssql-jdbc-9.2.1.jre8.jar
POSTGRE=deployment/libs/postgresql-42.2.19.jar
XDB=deployment/libs/xmlparserv2-18.3.0.0.jar,deployment/libs/xdb-21.3.0.0.jar


spark2-submit\
  --jars "${OJDBC}",${MSSQL}",${POSTGRE},${XDB}" \
  --master yarn \
  --deploy-mode cluster \
  worker_main.py
```

Maybe I just did not find compatible versions of the libraries? Or could there be some other problem, like missing CLASSPATH configuration?

Comment: You can try to unjar your jars to see if the missing class is in. A quick look @ https://mvnrepository.com/search?q=oracle+xdb shows at least a couple of XDB jars, so I suspect some compatibility issues :(...

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I already looked in the jar and the class is indeed in.